# Can I have a collections report removed from my credit history?

Tags: consumer-protection, debt, credit-report

I have a collections report on my credit history. The credit card company raised the minimum payment without notifying me or raising the automatic payment I set up for the minimum amount. I hadn't checked on any of my credit card accounts for a while just waiting for the automatic payments to eventually pay them off. Since they raised the minimum payment, I was not making the minimum for months and they sent my debt to collections.

I would like to get the collections off of my credit report—not just making it say that the debt is paid, but removing the fact that it ever went to collections.

Is there any way to remove a collections report like this from one's credit history?

Comment: Did they correctly state the new minimum payment on your monthly statement at the time?  Did you read your statement?  Do you have reason to think they were obliged to notify you in some way besides that?

Comment: @NateEldredge I imagine they did.  I wouldn't know, as I set up an automated monthly payment and found out about the situation after it was sent to collections.  I did not read it, as I set up an automated monthly payment.  The reason would be that I set up an automated monthly payment.  The reason to automate is so you don't have to monitor, right?

Comment: Not right.  I am pretty sure that the credit card company and the credit agency would reject the proposition that setting up an automatic payment absolves you of the responsibility to read your statements, would deny that they ever suggested that the one could take the place of the other, and would argue that a message in your statement *did* notify you of the change.

Comment: In particular, I'll bet if you check your credit card account agreement, you'll see you agreed to something like "I promise to promptly review my statement every month when it is made available to me", without any rider like "unless I set up automatic payment".

Answer (score 4):

You have a right to post an explanation of a disputed matter, but not necessarily a right to remove a truthful statement of fact, even if it exists for an understandable reason.

Comment: Is there really no way to fight it?  The reason to automate is so you don't have to monitor, right?  And, if so, and I set up the automation, shouldn't they have to let me know that they raised the minimum payment?  Otherwise, they're tricking a lot of people, right?  This for sure has happened to tons of people.  Should I look into class action?

Comment: @user3146 The credit reporting agency didn't make a false statement of fact, nor did the merchant bank operating the credit card. They made have engaged in a practice that was in your view unfair that made your nonpayment understandable (and perhaps even legally excusable in terms of fees for late payments and default interest), but it is true that they raised the minimum payment (which they are allowed to do prospectively) and it is true that you didn't pay the amount of the new minimum payment.